# Setting buildType attribute for specific flavour at android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-productflavors, android-studio-3.2

Is it possible to change a buildType attribute like debuggable for a specific build flavor?

I am trying setting it up using applicationVariants like this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.name == "flavorQuaRelease") {
        variant.buildType.debuggable = true
    }
}
```

but got this error:

```
Cannot set readonly property: debuggable for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ReadOnlyBuildType
```

Looks like a dead end.

I have 4 flavours, 2 build types. If i do by adding another build type i will have 24 different build options. Too much. 
Should be a better way to do it.